# Linux-0.11, the code of the function of file_write is error in the File_dev.c

Tags: linux

```
int file_write(struct m_inode * inode, struct file * filp, char * buf, int count){

off_t pos;
int block,c;
struct buffer_head * bh;
char * p;
int i=0;

.......

if (!(filp->f_flags & O_APPEND)) {

    filp->f_pos = pos; 
    inode->i_ctime = CURRENT_TIME;
}

}
```

I think:

```
int file_write(struct m_inode * inode, struct file * filp, char * buf, int count){

off_t pos, tmp;
int block,c;
struct buffer_head * bh;
char * p;
int i=0;


if (filp->f_flags & O_APPEND)
    pos = inode->i_size;   
else
    pos = filp->f_pos;  
    tmp = pos;

.......

if (!(filp->f_flags & O_APPEND)) {

    filp->f_pos = tmp; 
    inode->i_ctime = CURRENT_TIME;
}

}
```

otherwise  int the file_read filp->pos is error.
please Verify my ideas! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if opened as O_APPEND, file_write always writes to the end of the file (so at offset i_size) and updates i_size. And if not opened as O_APPEND, file_write writes to wherever f_pos is, and updates f_pos.

I think you expect file_write when not opened as O_APPEND to keep f_pos constant, which is not how it works I think.

Comment: If not opened as O_APPEND , as you said , in  the file_read , what is  the value of the filp->f_pos?  if correct, the address of source should be  filp->f_pos + bh->data ,but file_write lters the value of filp->f_pos, the address of source is the end of a file.

Comment: If you can, you verify with an example the value of filp->f_pos. In the situation,you write the same file repeatedly,the address of each time is error.

Comment: f_pos is what `ftell()` returns. Example for a file opened without O_APPEND: after open(), f_pos is 0. During the writing, the local `pos` is incremented by `count`. At the end, `f_pos` is set to the updated `pos` value. And so on for successive calls. Here's the source I am looking at: http://pastebin.com/sxjMKLCz

Comment: file_read wil be error,  if it use the  the updated pos value. so I think in file_write  the pos have some  questions.